# Taylor series of the inverse of $x^4+x$

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, inverse

I would like to expand the inverse function of

$$g(x) := x^4+x $$

in a taylor series at the point x = 0.

I calculated the first and second derivate at x = 0 with the rule of 
the derivation of an inverse function. Theoretically, this process 
could be continued for higher derivates.

But I would like to have an easier method to calculate higher derivates
of an inverse function in order to calculate the taylor series.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Try looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Comment: A good approach, but the formula still seems to be quite complicated.

Comment: Series reversion is available in CAS and produces (using Lagrange inversion) :  $$x - x^4 + 4\,x^7 - 22\,x^{10} + 140\,x^{13} - 969\,x^{16} + 7084\,x^{19} - 53820\,x^22 +
420732\,x^{25}+O(x^{28})$$
These coefficients appear in [OEIS A002293](https://oeis.org/A002293) and [OEIS A137211](https://oeis.org/A137211) (Generalized $4$-Catalan numbers?).

Comment: @raymond Which convergence radius has this expansion ?

Comment: The radius of convergence is not large.  I get $\sqrt[3]{27/256}$.

Comment: @mark How did you calculate the radius ?

Comment: @Peter I've added an answer to address your question.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118532/what-was-lamberts-solution-to-xmx-q/118762#118762.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general you may use series reversion to get the taylor expansion of the inverse of a function given by a Taylor series. See for example at [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) or in [A&S page 16](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_16.htm).

But for functions like $\;f(x):=x+x^n\;$ with $n>1$ integer we may obtain the expansion of the inverse in explicit form as shown by Tom Copeland in his paper ["Discriminating Deltas, Depressed Equations, and Generalized Catalan Numbers"](http://tcjpn.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/discrdeltas9-6-20122.pdf) (just before chapter $5$).

For $n=4$ and using the generating function of [OEIS A002293](https://oeis.org/A002293) we 'guess' directly the solution :
$$f^{-1}(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^{3n+1}}{3n+1}\binom{4n}{n}$$
and using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20sum%28%28-x%29%5E%283%2an%2b1%29/%283%2an%2b1%29%2abinomial%284%2an,n%29,n=0..infinity%29) or by studying the asymptotic of $\binom{4n}{n}\,x^{3n}$ with Stirling's formula we obtain the equivalence :
$$\sqrt{2\,\pi\, n\, 3/4}\;\binom{4n}{n}x^{3n}\sim \frac{(4n/e)^{4n}\,x^{3n}}{(n/e)^{n}(3n/e)^{3n}}\sim \frac{4^{4n}\,x^{3n}}{3^{3n}}\sim \left(\frac{4^4\,x^{3}}{3^3}\right)^n$$
showing that $\,|x|^3$ shouldn't be larger than $\dfrac{3^3}{4^4}=\dfrac{27}{256}$ as quickly found by Mark McClure.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks @Peter! I'll have to look at the details of Tom Copeland's paper myself. Cheers,

Comment: BTW, the ratio 27/256 is precisely that for the coefficients of the discriminant curve for the equation.

Comment: @TomCopeland: you probably mean the discriminant of $x^4+x-y$ relatively to $x$ which is $-256\,y^3-27$ since all the coefficients disappear from the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation) except the $a^3e^3$ and $a^2d^4$ ones. Nice observation (allowing I think generalizations for $n$ integer and $n\neq 4\cdots$) and interesting paper. Thanks for both!

Comment: @RaymondManzoni : See my question on the discriminants of equations of this form. Hadn't really thought about the region of convergence of the series for the inverse and its relation to the discriminant before, so nice answers for me.

Comment: Graphically, the point where the vertical line b=-1 meets the discriminant curve in Figs. 1 and 2 should give the convergence limit for the series.  This case is for n=4. n=1 is a degenerate case with no limit.

Comment: The limit for the convergence of the inverse series for $x^n + x$ for $n>1$ should be $(\frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^n})^{\frac{1}{n-1}}=(n-1) (\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{n}{n-1}}$.

Comment: For an asymptotic approach to the convergence, see p. 775 of "Function Series, Catalan Numbers, and Random Walks on Trees" by Bajunaid, Cohen, Colonna, and Singman

Comment: Available [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.5185&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Thanks to share @Tom Copeland !

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to Peter's question in the comments, namely, how did I deduce the radius of convergence to be $\sqrt[3]{27/256}$?  I have no proof as the technique is experimental, relying completely on Mathematica.  But, this is how I did it.

First, we invert the series using Mathematica's `InverseSeries` command.

```
invSeries = InverseSeries[Series[x + x^4, {x, 0, 30}]]
```

[image]

Next, we use `FindSequenceFunction` to generate a closed form expression for the non-zero coefficients.

```
a[n_] = FullSimplify[FindSequenceFunction[
   DeleteCases[CoefficientList[Normal[invSeries], x], 0], n]]
```

[image]

Clearly, this step has some issues.  It doesn't always work and, even when it appears to work, there's no guarantee that it works for all $n$.  Of course, we can check that the formula works for fairly large $n$, but there's still no proof here.  Furthermore, this expression is clearly not as nice as the one found by Raymond!

Now that we have a candidate for the $a_n$s, though, we can easily use a ratio test to find the radius of convergence.

```
Limit[a[n]/a[n + 1], n -> Infinity]
(* Out: -27/256 *)
```

Taking the absolute value and accounting for the fact that only every 3rd term is non-zero, we get $\sqrt[3]{27/256}$.

Comment: Useful method (in many cases) using Mma. Thanks to share! Cheers,

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Also, see my comments on discriminants above.